# Activations Quantization for Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am using Caffe to execute some Convolutional Neural Networks. However, my idea is executing the inference procedure by using quantized activations. Does anybody know the best way to do so? I've been looking up Ristretto, but I am not sure whether that framework quantizes the activations or only the weights. Does anybody know anything about that?

Otherwise, I've heard on some forums that caffev2 implements something related to quantization but however I am not able to see anything about that on the official website.

Thank you all for your attention,
Francisco.